# How to show $F^\prime (x)=f(x)$ at every Lebesgue point of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, harmonic-analysis

Real and Complex Analysis, Page 141 $\textbf{7.11 Theorem}$
If $f\in L^1(\Bbb R^1) $ and

$$F(x)=\int^x_{-\infty}f\,dm\qquad x\in \Bbb R$$

then $F' (x)=f(x)$ at every Lebesgue point of $f$, hence $a.e.-m $.

In the proof, it only let $\Delta x$ be elements of $\{\delta_i\}$ which is a sequence of positive numbers that converges to $0$, why is it enough?
In the usual way, We have to take $0<|\Delta x|<\delta$ for some $\delta>0$.

Answer (score 0):

> **Defintion** $x$ is Lebesgue point if 
>   $$f(x) = \lim_{\stackrel{x\in I}{|I|\to 0}}\frac{1}{|I|} \int_{I} f(y)dm(y)$$

If $x$ is a Lebesgue point then
$$ f(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{|[x-h,x+h]|} \int_{[x-h,x+h]} f(y)dm(y)\\= \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2h} \int_{x-h}^{x+h} f(y)dm(y)\\=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{1}{2h} \left(\int^{x+h}_{-\infty}f\,dm -\int^{x-h}_{-\infty}f\,dm \right)\\=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{F(x+h) -F(x-h)}{2h} \\= \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x) }{2h}+\frac{F(x) -F(x-h)}{2h} \\= F'(x) $$

Comment: Do you *assume* that $F'(x)$ exists or does that follow from the calculation?

Comment: In fact you could half interval I did not want to it twice. Using half interval  I=[x,x+h] or I= [x-h,x] it works as well. The essential point is x stay in I as $h\to 01$

Comment: I am not an expert for Lebesgue/measure theory, but according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_point, the limit is only considered for intervals *centered* at $x$, not for an arbitrary sequence of intervals *containing* $x$.

Comment: Read this carefully. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: I also copy this for you: We can relax the conditions on f still further and suppose that it is merely locally integrable. In that case, we can conclude that the function F is differentiable almost everywhere and $F′(x) = f(x) $ almost everywhere. On the real line this statement is equivalent to Lebesgue's differentiation theorem. FROM  HERE https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus